# Field Level Encryption In Big Query

Tags: encryption, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, aes

Our team is currently exploring the ways to encrypt PII data on the field level within BigQuery and we found out the following way to encrypt/decrypt using [Crypto-JS](https://github.com/brix/crypto-js):

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION encrypt(_text STRING) RETURNS STRING LANGUAGE js AS
"""
  let key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse("<key>");
  let options = { iv: CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse("<iv>"), mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC };
  let _encrypt = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(_text, key, options);
  return _encrypt;
""";
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION decrypt(_text STRING) RETURNS STRING LANGUAGE js AS
"""
  let key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse("<key>");
  let options = { iv: CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse("<iv>"), mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC };
  let _decrypt = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(_text, key, options).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
  return _decrypt;
""" OPTIONS (library="gs://path/to/Crypto-JS/crypto-js.js");

-- query to encrypt fields
SELECT
  <fields>, encrypt(<pii-fields>)
FROM
  `<project>.<dataset>.<table>`

-- query to decrypt fields
SELECT
      <fields>, decrypt(<pii-fields>)
    FROM
      `<project>.<dataset>.<table>`
```

I am trying to benchmark the performance of AES CBC encryption & decryption using Crypto JS library in the big query before deploying it into our production. We found out the rate of data to encrypt & decrypt is growing exponential per records with increasing number of data compared to the usual query. However with the increasing number of data to process, the progress of processing per record & record processing time is improving.

As there are no available documentation regarding this, could someone from the community help provide better ways, optimize query, best practices to use field level encryption & decryption within the big query?

[image]

Comment: Please submit the form linked from [this feature request on the issue tracker](http://issuetracker.google.com/issues/111927939) for access to built-in functions for encryption and decryption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BigQuery now supports [encryption functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/aead_encryption_functions). From the documentation, here is a self-contained example that creates some keysets and uses them to encrypt data. In practice, you would want to store the keysets in a real table so that you can later use them to decrypt the ciphertext.

```
WITH CustomerKeysets AS (
  SELECT 1 AS customer_id, KEYS.NEW_KEYSET('AEAD_AES_GCM_256') AS keyset UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, KEYS.NEW_KEYSET('AEAD_AES_GCM_256') UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, KEYS.NEW_KEYSET('AEAD_AES_GCM_256')
), PlaintextCustomerData AS (
  SELECT 1 AS customer_id, 'elephant' AS favorite_animal UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'walrus' UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 'leopard'
)
SELECT
  pcd.customer_id,
  AEAD.ENCRYPT(
    (SELECT keyset
     FROM CustomerKeysets AS ck
     WHERE ck.customer_id = pcd.customer_id),
    pcd.favorite_animal,
    CAST(pcd.customer_id AS STRING)
  ) AS encrypted_animal
FROM PlaintextCustomerData AS pcd;
```

Edit: if you want to decrypt using AES-CBC with PKCS padding (it's not clear what kind of padding you are using in your example) you can use the [`KEYS.ADD_KEY_FROM_RAW_BYTES` function](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/aead_encryption_functions#keysadd_key_from_raw_bytes) to create a keyset, then call `AEAD.DECRYPT_STRING` or `AEAD.DECRYPT_BYTES`. For example:

```
SELECT
  AEAD.DECRYPT_STRING(
    KEYS.ADD_KEY_FROM_RAW_BYTES(b'', 'AES_CBC_PKCS', b'1234567890123456'),
    FROM_HEX('deed2a88e73dccaa30a9e6e296f62be27db30db16f76d3f42c85d31db3f46376'),
    '')
```

This returns `abcdef`. The IV is expected to be the first 16 bytes of the ciphertext.

Comment: Thanks this is useful to encrypt data but I am also trying to decrypt data (AES128 CBC) from big query. How to create a keyset from json with initialization vector?

Comment: I added an example.

Comment: Yes! I use PKCS padding as well and able to decrypt the ciphertext with IV. However, I am trying instead of creating a new keyset to encrypt data (AES_CBC_PKCS). When I pass the function KEYS.ADD_KEY_FROM_RAW_BYTES(b'', 'AES_CBC_PKCS', b'<key>') to AEAD.ENCRYPT(). I am getting an error `AEAD.ENCRYPT failed: Encryption is not supported using AES-CBC keys`. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, you cannot use encryption with that type of key (this i

Comment: You cannot encrypt using keys of that type, as explained [in the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/aead_encryption_functions#keysadd_key_from_raw_bytes). It would be best to reencrypt your data using a new keyset, since AES-CBC is not known as a good option anymore.